# join for different monads in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monads

I know I can use join to remove the first level of list

`join [["dog"]]`  " output `["dog"]`

But why the following is not working

```
join $ (Just ["dog"]) 

got error:
Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘Maybe’
```

We know `Maybe` and `[]` are both Monad in Haskell,

```
join(Monad m)=> m(m a) -> m a
```

`Maybe` is Monad

`[]` is Monad

What is wrong with that?

It seems to me join only for the same type of Monad, 
please correct me if I'm wrong.

Is there any function similar to join for any Monads like the example I's given above?

I know I can do it as following

```
fromJust (Just ["dog"]) 

"output:  ["dog"]
```

But I need to know Just in advance.

Comment: `join` doesn't simply remove an outer monad; it *merges* them, in a monad-specific way. Even `join [["dog"]]` doesn't simply remove the outer list; it concatenates the inner lists: `join [["dog"], ["cat"]] == ["dog", "cat"]`.

Comment: Can you clarify what is "monad-specific way", any reference or doc would be appreciated.

Comment: @AronLee `join` is defined as part of the definition of a Monad. Each Monad defines `join` differently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `m` in `join :: Monad m => m (m a) -> m a` is the same Monad everywhere it appears. If you had `Just (Just "dog")`, then you have two `Maybe` monads and your `join` will work perfectly. Similarly to your list example.

Pulling things out of a Monad cannot be generalized, which is part of the power of Monads. Consider that if you *could* do that, it would be trivial to strip out the type safety of the IO Monad!

To go from `Just ["dog"] -> ["dog"]`, you just need a `Maybe a -> a` You could use `Data.Maybe.fromJust`, but `maybe` is safer (what if you have `Nothing` instead?)